# Create Stored Procedure with column Name & Value For Dynamic Search

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a stored procedure with two parameters `ColumnName` and `ColumnValue` for searching

My query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE @ColumnName Like  @ColumnValue  + '%'
```

but it's return 0 result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need Dynamic SQL for that. What you have written is searching the @columnValue value in the @ColumnName value. So if your column is `foo` and the value is `bar` it searches if `'foo'` LIKE `'bar%'`

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 
N'SELECT * FROM TableName 
WHERE ' + QuoteName(@ColumnName) + ' LIKE @val+''%'''

EXECUTE sp_executesql 
@SQL,
N'@val varchar(100)',
@val = @ColumnValue;
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SEARCH_CLIENT, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ' + Like  ''.

Comment: @jyparask.... '''  this format should be not work...it  will not consider as a string.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I know about injection, but it is not specified how is this going to be used and i don't make any assumptions. For all i know this is going to be run from SSMS.

Comment: It's Wotking Thanks For Reply

Comment: @MikaelEriksson 1st of all i accept the whooping as you are totally 100% right. 2nd i will change the answer because of 1st...3rd you could have provided the right answer. After all in means of SQL writing, though bad in concept, it still works. I am just saying...

Comment: @MikaelEriksson There you go... Again thanks for pointing it out.